# Laravel : Records filter

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, laravel

I have a page displaying records from `DB` regarding products, I want to add filters for them in the right sidebar, My question is, What is the best way to fetch records on "On click".

Currently the filter have the categories, Where a user can click and the related category products will show up. There is also an option for price range, etc

what i can think of right now is :

- Have a separate route and method for each category etc.

I am completely blank.

Comment: Yes, definitely create a separate route for that like : url/{filter}/{filter_value}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO I would go for a GET with querystring parameters using the same index route you have for listing products, i.e.:

```
GET /products?category=car
```

This way you dont have to declare different routes.

I have found that using this package https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter makes coding easier when you have to filter model lists.